# using Getopt::Std and Getopt::Long in a Perl script

Tags: perl, getopt, getopt-long

I have an existing Perl script which has many command line options which are processed using `Getopt::Std` (`getopts` function). But, I want to add 2 new options: `--testrun` and `--cfgarray`.

I used `use Getopt::Long;` and `GetOptions('testrun' => \$test_flag);` "--testrun" takes no argument.  I simply used it as a flag like `if($test_flag)`. It works when run separately. But, since in my Perl script there is both `use Getopt::Long;` and `use Getopt::Std;`, I get error:

> unknown options

from `getopts` api (when it is called before `GetOptions`). Can both `Getopt::Std` and `Getopt::Long` be used in a single Perl script?

Answer (score 4):

[`Getopt::Std`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Getopt/Std.html) and [`Getopt::Long`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Getopt/Long.html) both just interpret [`@ARGV`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#@ARGV), so if you fiddle with that, it's *theoretically* possible to use both of them in one script, or to call `GetOptions` more than once. **However,** I wouldn't recommend it - just use `Getopt::Long`.

This code:

```
use Getopt::Std;
getopts('a:b', \my %opts) or die "Bad options\n";
```

can be translated into:

```
use Getopt::Long;
GetOptions(\my %opts, 'a=s', 'b') or die "Bad options\n";
```

and then you can add more options, and long options. Here, I've added a short alias `-t` for the option `--testrun`, just to demonstrate:

```
use Getopt::Long;
GetOptions(\my %opts, 'a=s', 'b',
    'testrun|t', 'cfgarray' ) or die "Bad options\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK you cannot use both, but [Getopt::Long](https://metacpan.org/pod/Getopt::Long) supports also short options, so you could stick with it.

Comment: ok thanks. Then I want to use GetOptions to do getopts("yjfei:o:j:z:", \%opts); . In GetOptions (Getopt::Long;) can we feed arguments to hash ? and same time I want to get some values to an array. (as i mentioned in question. Can we do both?) I also read that we cannot call GetOptions more than once in program. can you please give me an example were GetOptions is uused to get  getopts("yjfei:o:j:z:", \%opts) into that hash opts. and also get 3 integers into an array as well. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please have a look at [Getopt::Long](https://metacpan.org/pod/Getopt::Long)! It's all there: E.g. [Storing options values in a hash](https://metacpan.org/pod/Getopt::Long#Storing-options-values-in-a-hash) or [Options with multiple values](https://metacpan.org/pod/Getopt::Long#Options-with-multiple-values)